# SwiftUI App Shows Realm Changes but Not New Objects

Tags: swiftui, realm, combine

*Realm 10.7.3, Xcode 12.4, macOS 11.2.3*

I am experimenting with Realm and Combine+SwiftUI. When I make changes to my data in Realm Studio, they immediately reflect in my app's UI as expected. But when I **add** or **delete** an object, my app UI does not change.

Here's my model definition:

```
//--- Model ---
class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
  @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
  @objc dynamic var text = ""
}
```

Here's my view model:

```
//--- View Model ---
class ItemModel: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = ItemModel()
  var token: NotificationToken? = nil
  @Published var items = [Item]()
  
  init(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Item.self)
    items = Array(results)
   
    token = results.observe { [weak self] _ in
      print("-- updated --")
      self?.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }
  
  deinit{
    token?.invalidate()
  }
}
```

And last of all, here's my SwiftUI view:

```
//--- View ---
struct ItemView: View {
  @StateObject private var model = ItemModel.shared

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
      VStack(spacing: 7){
        ForEach(model.items, id: \._id) { item in
          Text(item.text)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why my app won't show new/deleted objects and only edits? If I rebuild my app, the new/deleted objects are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Results objects are live-updating objects and always reflect the current state of those objects in Realm.

However, if you cast your Realm Results object to an array

```
items = Array(results)
```

It 'disconnects' those objects ( the results ) from Realm and it (they) are no longer live updating.

Additionally Realm Results objects are lazily-loaded, meaning that they are only loaded into memory when needed so thousands of objects take up almost no space.

Storing them in an array changes that - they are *all* loaded into memory and could overwhelm the device.

Best practice is to leave Realm Collections (Results, Lists) as that type of object throughout the duration of using them instead of casting to an array.

Comment: Well that turned out to be a lot simpler to fix than I expected.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That makes sense about the object lazy-loading. I wasn't sure if a Realm `Results` object could be set as `@Published` so I started with an array.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum It's a common issue. Keep Results and Lists pure as much as possible. It's tempting to`.map` or swift `.filter` etc but as soon as you apply those Swifty functions to a Collection it well, is no longer a Collection. So doing things the Realm way will reduce future problems and keep your code cleaner.