# Filtering query for Realm

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, realm

I have a function which prints all the objects in my realm table to a table view. I would like to be able to filter these objects by their "muscle" property.

Here's my DB helper functions:

```
func getMusclesCount()-> Int {
    let storedExercise = realm.objects(StoredExercise.self)
    return storedExercise.count
    
}

//MARK:- getAllMuscelsNames
func getAllMusclesNames()-> [String] {
    var musclesName = [String]()
    let storedExercise = realm.objects(StoredExercise.self)
    for exercise in storedExercise {
        print("Muscle = \(exercise.muscle)")
        musclesName.append(exercise.name)
    }
    return musclesName
}
```

Here's my Table View Controller class :

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DBHelper.shared.getAllMusclesNames().count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    let muscle = DBHelper.shared.getAllMusclesNames()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = muscle
    return cell
}
```

I've tried adding .Filter to 'let storedExercise' but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly. Any assitance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A couple of things. It's best practice to include your Realm models in the question so we know what they look like. Secondly, you probably don't want to cast your realm results to an array - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225254/swiftui-app-shows-realm-changes-but-not-new-objects/67232083#67232083). Lastly, how does `getMusclesCount` work with the rest of the code in the question, I don't see any references to it.

Comment: Oh, and last-lastly, you are not going to want to populate your tableView in that fashion. Tableview delegate methods are supposed to be lightweight and fast, pulling data from disk or storage each time is not a good idea - you'll want to keep a `results` object in memory for that - which also goes back to not casting the results to an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your StoredExercise model looks like this

```
class StoredExercise: Object {
  @objc dynamic var muscle = ""
}
```

then to get all of the exercises that are for the biceps, it's this

```
let bicepResults = realm.objects(StoredExercise.self).filter("muscle == 'biceps'")
```