# Why SwiftUI List crashes when loading images from Realm DB? RAM reaches limit

Tags: memory, swiftui, realm

I have persisted about 7000 images onto a Realm DB so they can be viewed offline. The App is working pretty well except when loading a very long SwiftUI List. I believe all the images are stored on RAM as user scrolls down, because I can actually see RAM increasing when testing. The problem is that if there are sufficient Images in the List, RAM gets full and app crashes.

They claim that SwiftUI List is like UITableView reusable cell, so why doesn't it deallocate the memory for past images in list?

```
List(searchResults(results: results), id: \.self) { product in 
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                ForEach(0...imageListGetter().count - 1, id: \.self) {i in
                    
                    imageListGetter()[i]
                }}}

//each image is added like this to the list, they are stored as Data into Realm DB and then passed as uiImage to SwiftUI Image

imageList.append(Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imageLocation1.data!)!)
```

I am saving images as data to the Realm, and loading them as uiImage to the Image view.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Realm objects are lazily loaded which means thousands of objects have a tiny RAM footprint. However, casting to or storing in an array, looses that advantage so they all gobble up memory, overwhelming the device. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225254/swiftui-app-shows-realm-changes-but-not-new-objects/67232083#67232083). One option is to not cast or store in an array and use the Results as the datasource. The other option is to use pagination and load a smaller amount of data at a time.

Comment: Oh, Realm is not generally the best solution for image storage; thumbnails (a couple hundred Kb) are ok. The size of your data was not clear but thought I would mention it.

Comment: You are correct once again Mr Jay! I got rid of casting the results to the array and voila! No more RAM crashes. On the other hand, I am saving over 7000 images  to a Realm, average 500kb per image, and it works pretty well. A whole lot faster than FileManager with CoreData.

Anyway, thanks again for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm objects are lazily loaded which means thousands of objects have a tiny RAM footprint.

However, casting to or storing those objects in an array looses that advantage so they all gobble up memory, overwhelming the device.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225254/swiftui-app-shows-realm-changes-but-not-new-objects/67232083#67232083) for more reading on that

There are a couple of solutions.

One option is to not cast or store the Realm objects in an array and use the Results as the datasource.

The other option if you must store the data in an array, is to use pagination and load a smaller amount of data at a time.

There are a number of advantages to the first option so I would suggest leaving the objects in a Results object - it acts very much like an array so I can be a great dataSource for tableViews etc.